# XAMPP: Alias issue - Error 404

Tags: apache, xampp, alias, httpd.conf

I am trying to alias this:
/htdocs/test/index.php

In my xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf, I have the following entry:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
<IfModule mime_module>
    Alias /test/ "D:/Installation/xampp/htdocs/test"
    <Directory "D:/Installation/xampp/test">
           <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "index.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

When I go to http://localhost/test/, I get the directory listing shown. When I type in this URL- http://localhost/test/, I want to have this file- /test/index.php opened.

When I try to go to this URL directly "localhost/test/index.php", I get "Error 404 Object not found" message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Find the section of your httpd-xampp.conf file with the following:

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Add "index.php" to the DirectoryIndex line.

- [Apache Module mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html)
- [Apache Display / Change a Default Page Other Than index.html](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-display-or-change-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml/)

Comment: The code you mentioned above is already included in the httpd.conf file. I also tried including that code in httpd-xampp.conf but there was no effect of it. Any thing else you can recommend?